# locate invisible utf8 characters in mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have a database in where I have found some field with NON UTF8 characters inside.
In fact, if i edit the field value with phpmyadmin, copy the value of the field, paste it on notepad++, and change the encoding, I see this character `ï»¿` while there is nothing if i change the charset to utf8 no BOM.

I need to find a way to search and delete all those ANSI visibile characters in the mySQL tables, consider that those character are visible only if I paste the value in notepad++

please if someone has an idea, anything is apreciated.

this question is related to this problem:[another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216384/locate-those-different-charset-characters-that-mess-up-the-database)

Comment: `ï»¿` is the (not needed) BOM for UTF-8, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

> select * from tableName where fieldName regexp '[^ -~]';